# Does Eclipse(C++) has any shortcut like ctrl+D in Vs Code?

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio-code, shortcut

I knew about this shortcut.

After selecting a piece of text:

- Next occurrence is ctrl+k.
- Previous occurrence is ctrl+shift+k.

But I want to find another short cut like Ctrl+D in vscode to multi select, and only need to edit one time, with ctr+k I need to edit so many times.

Comment: Seems newer version `4.24` has this ability, called `Multi selection down relative to anchor selection` - `Ctrl-Alt-J`. 
https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.24/platform.php 
https://www.reddit.com/r/eclipse/comments/f5vfdd/is_there_a_way_to_enable_multiselect_in_eclipse/

Answer (score 2):

There are **multi-select commands**, but **by default no keyboard shortcuts** are assigned to them.

You could assign keyboard shortcuts to the following multi-select commands yourself in the **preferences *General > Keys*** (hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> twice):

- ***Add all matches to multi-selection***, e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>
- ***Multi selection down relative to anchor selection***, e.g. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>
- ***Multi selection up relative to anchor selection***, e.g. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>
- ***Multi caret down***, e.g. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>
- ***Multi caret up***, e.g. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>
- ***End multi-selection***, e.g. <kbd>Esc</kbd>

See also my [video showing this in action](https://youtu.be/zDJtVYAJwyY?t=527).